# best way to use Coupon code in Guest and Login User

Tags: django

In django what is the best way to use coupon code for guest user and login user for per coupon per order?

my order model is like

```
# models.py

class Orders(models.Model):
    order_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    total_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    ordertime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    customer= models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    guest =models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
```

In my opinion I should create a coupon model like something

```
 class Coupon(models.Model):
     coupon = models.charField(max_length=50)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end saved in `sessions`

## Set a session value

request.session['order'] = 'coupon_applied'

## Delete a session value

del request.session['order']